# Pktgen Installation error for missing rte_config.h

Tags: dpdk

Trying to install PktGen with DPDK 21.11, however I am getting the below error

```
[1/69] Compiling C object lib/common/libcommon.a.p/copyright_info.c.o
FAILED: lib/common/libcommon.a.p/copyright_info.c.o
cc -Ilib/common/libcommon.a.p -Ilib/common -I../lib/common -I/include -fdiagnostics-color=always -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -O3 -march=native -mavx -mavx2 -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-pedantic -Wno-format-truncation -fPIC -include rte_config.h -march=native -mno-avx512f -MD -MQ lib/common/libcommon.a.p/copyright_info.c.o -MF lib/common/libcommon.a.p/copyright_info.c.o.d -o lib/common/libcommon.a.p/copyright_info.c.o -c ../lib/common/copyright_info.c
cc1: fatal error: rte_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I think I am missing some environmental variable?

```
23:45:08 [root:~/Pktgen-DPDK] dev* ± echo  $RTE_SDK
/root/repo/gNB_CU/ngp/thirdparty/dpdk/dpdk-21.11/
23:45:41 [root:~/Pktgen-DPDK] dev* ± echo  $RTE_TARGET
x86_64-native-linux-gcc
23:45:46 [root:~/Pktgen-DPDK] dev* ± pkg-config --libs libdpdk
-Wl,--as-needed -L/lib64 -lrte_node -lrte_graph -lrte_flow_classify -lrte_pipeline -lrte_table -lrte_pdump -lrte_port -lrte_fib -lrte_ipsec -lrte_vhost -lrte_stack -lrte_security -lrte_sched -lrte_reorder -lrte_rib -lrte_dmadev -lrte_regexdev -lrte_rawdev -lrte_power -lrte_pcapng -lrte_member -lrte_lpm -lrte_latencystats -lrte_kni -lrte_jobstats -lrte_ip_frag -lrte_gso -lrte_gro -lrte_gpudev -lrte_eventdev -lrte_efd -lrte_distributor -lrte_cryptodev -lrte_compressdev -lrte_cfgfile -lrte_bpf -lrte_bitratestats -lrte_bbdev -lrte_acl -lrte_timer -lrte_hash -lrte_metrics -lrte_cmdline -lrte_pci -lrte_ethdev -lrte_meter -lrte_net -lrte_mbuf -lrte_mempool -lrte_rcu -lrte_ring -lrte_eal -lrte_telemetry -lrte_kvargs
23:45:54 [root:~/Pktgen-DPDK] dev* ± pkg-config --cflags libdpdk
-I/include -include rte_config.h -march=native -mno-avx512f
23:46:06 [root:~/Pktgen-DPDK] dev* ±
```

Any suggestion where I might have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in DPDK installation path.

```
wget http://fast.dpdk.org/rel/dpdk-21.11.tar.xz
tar -xf dpdk-21.11.tar.xz
cd dpdk-21.11/
meson -Dexamples=all build
ninja -C build
cd build
ninja install
ldconfig
```

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig/

Once this was done, installation was successful.